# How to create dynamic array of strings where starts from null and length varies?

Tags: javascript

How to create dynamic array of strings where starts from null and length varies?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: If your using push them the length will be updated automatically? Please give some more detail

Comment: `[]` is a JavaScript array in this context. It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: `.push` adds an element to the end of the array. It doesn't replace anything. Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). It seems you just have a misunderstanding of what `.push` does?

Comment: JSON has as much to do with your problem as flying fishes (i.e. nothing). You seem to confuse objects / arrays with JSON.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with closures either. Why do you think it does? Just use `.push` to add a value to the array and you are done!

Comment: *"but my Add button (not in this demo) not works"* Well, what exactly do you expect it to do? It seems to wok fine for me, elements are getting added to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I understand, but when you push an item into an aray - you automatically increment the length of that array:

```
var colors = []; //colors.length = 0; colors is an empty array
colors.push('blue'); //colors.length=1; colors=['blue'];
colors.push('green'); //colors.length=2;colors=['blue','green'];
```

and you access it via the length property

```
var colorsLength = colors.length //after the above - this will give 2
```

to add this value to local storage use the following:

```
localStorage.setItem('colors',colorsLength );
```

and then to retrieve that information use

```
var colors=localStorage.getItem('colorsLength');
```

note that localStorage and sessionStorage store information as strings -so you will need to parse it to convert it into a number if you want to do calculations on it.

if you want to store the actual array - then you will need to stringify it to enter it into the local storage.

Comment: Be aware that the length is just the highest index value + 1. So if you set `colors[1001] = 'bleugh'` then `colors.length === 1002`

Comment: granted - but the OP indicated he was pushing the elements which adds the element to the end of the existing array at the next index number.

Comment: True. I was just adding some extra info.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage stores strings not objects (or arrays).  You have to store it as a string so this:

```
['blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', ...]
```

will turn into this:

```
blue,orange,yellow,green
```

When you read from localStorage initially, you can do:

```
var colors = [];
var colorStore = localStorage.getItem('colors');

if ( colorStore ) {
    colors = colorStore.split(/,/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the index of an item in an array is the same as its insertion order. So if you push 'blue' into the colors array, then

```
colors[0] === 'blue'
```

will be true.

At anytime you can get the length of an array using

```
colors.length
```